# Can't bind to 'matMenuTrigger' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Tags: javascript, npm, mean-stack, angular8, angular9

i try to use matMenuTrigger but i get this error 
Can't bind to 'matMenuTrigger' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

help please

Comment: Hello could you please output some code and give some more context.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to a missing import. Try adding

```
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';
```